# EF Core 2.1. How to revert migration "n" steps back

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to revert database migrations on N steps back, like,
"revert 2 migrations back"

I found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update) that we can pass parameter '0' which will revert a database to clean state.
`dotnet ef database update 0`

I am looking for something similar to: `dotnet ef database update -2`

*I know, that I can do this using migration's name. But I find that sometimes much easier just enter a number, than copy/paste migration name*

Comment: AFAIK you can do `dotnet ef database update <migration-name>`, where you have to specify the name of the migration you like to get to. It is not that convenient as -2, but at least it works.

Comment: There is no way out of the box, you may write your own script which does that for you.

Comment: This is supposed to work, to roll back to a named migration - `Update-Database NameOfPreviousMigration`. It doesn't seem to work correctly for me when using SQLLite.

Answer (score 5):

In package manager console, you can run the following command to rollback the migrations in your database:

```
Update-Database NameOfPreviousMigration
```

Then to the remove the migrations you can run the command `Remove-Migration` in PMC to remove the penultimate migration. Run this as many times to remove the migrations, e.g. run twice to remove the last 2 migrations. This command will also updated your `ModelSnapshot`.

Comment: The question is how to go steps back, not how to target a migration.  This is important for correcting bad database migration state between branches, where you will have to switch between branches to revert them one by one, as otherwise you will be reverting multiple steps at once.